# How can I completely shut off / inert my home alarm system?

Tags: electrical, alarm

I am asking more-or-less the same question as in this post: [How can I disconnect power to an ADT alarm system?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/100778/how-can-i-disconnect-power-to-an-adt-alarm-system)

The house has an ADT alarm installed by its previous owner. I am not paying for monitoring, so I see no real value in it. It has become a nuisance lately because there are battery-powered smoke detectors which signal back to the system, as I've recently discovered, do so on low battery.

I've attached some pictures to help with specifics. As it appears to me, the unit normally draws power from an A/C adapter next to the box, but also has a backup battery. My question: can I simply disconnect both, or would there be other power sources to feed the system's noise makers?

I'm wondering about the control panels... I assume they are hard-wired, but would they have their own internal back-up power or operate solely from their connection to the main unit?

This is one of two control panels (both are identical in appearance):
[image: One of two control panels]

Manual cover page to identify the specific model:
[image: Manual cover page]

Comment: Can you get model number off smoke detectors?

Answer (score 4):

*Note that it would be dangerous to go without some compliant smoke alarm system - in the comments, @Anthony X indicates there are other smoke detectors / smoke alarms present.*

I'd say it's 99%+ that the battery and power supply are the only two sources for the system and if you unplug them it will be down.  You might as well unplug the phone line connection on the right too.

Be sure to test the remaining smoke alarms, and make sure the system alarms as it should, and that there are still working smoke alarms in all the necessary areas.  At a minimum, you want one in every bedroom, and in the hallways outside of the bedromms, and make sure there's one on every floor of the house - including the basement.

I would probably check out all the existing smoke detectors and replace them with something current.  Smoke alarms don't last forever, I'd rest easier if I knew what I have and had confidence that it works as it should.

Comment: The house has a lot of redundancy wrt smoke detectors. The units which are enrolled with the alarm are battery powered and will operate independently; integration with the house alarm is an additional feature. In addition to these units, there are also hard-wired smoke detectors.

Comment: Are the hard wired smoke detectors separate from the ADT system?

Comment: I don't believe the hard-wired detectors are integrated with the alarm system. Pretty sure they are just wired in to the normal electrical system. Looking at the manual booklet, the cover illustration depicts the wireless alarms only; the hard-wired units look the same as I had in my last house which did not have an alarm system.

Comment: I have an ADT system and all but one of the smoke detectors are standard, hard wired.  There is one special one that is connected to the alarm system.  My control panels are similar and do not have back-up power.  Door and window sensors have batteries, but they die silently - no beeping.

Comment: Unplugging the phone may interrupt phone service if the installer didn't use an RJ31X or if the RJ31X fails to switch.